# char type declaration and verification

Tags: c++, comparison, c-strings, strcmp

How to check the char type? my variable input need to be a char, cause it contain letters and numbers.
If I use string instead of char, I don't have error with while, but I have error with cin.getline(input,10)

```
char input[10];
while(input != "1") //Error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified(use strncmp //instead)
{
cin.getline(input, 10);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string input;` for storing the input, and `std::getline (std::cin, input);` for reading the input?

Comment: Oh thx you sir, I did wrong, std::cin.getline(input) instead of std::getling(std::cin,input). Thx

Answer (score 0):

In expressions (with rare exception as for example when they are used in sizeof operator) arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

In this condition

```
while(input != "1")
```

there are compared addresses of the first character of the array `input` and of the first character of the string literal `"1"`.

Use instead standard C function `strcmp` declared in the header `<cstring>`.

Pay attention to that in your code snippet the array `input` is not initialized.  So before comparing it with something you have to initialize it.